# Повторить запрос при 202 коде Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rxjava2

Мне нужно реализовать повтор запроса если приходит 202 код используя RxJava 2, проблема в том что когда я пытаюсь это сделать, то при 202 коде в ответе от сервера пусто, а при успешном ответе приходит нужная модель, поэтому при 202 коде получаю ошибку, и дальнейшей обработки по коду ответа не происходит.

```
@GET("dogs")
fun getDogs(): Observable<Response<Any>>
```

Это обработка ответа

```
private inline fun <reified T> Observable<Response<Any>>.handle202(): Observable<T> {
        return this
            .flatMap {
                when (it.code()) {
                    HttpStatusCode.ACCEPTED -> {
                        Observable.timer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .flatMap {
                                this.flatMap {
                                    if (it.code() == HttpStatusCode.ACCEPTED) {
                                        throw HttpException(202, "", emptyMap(), "")
                                    }
                                    Observable.just(it.body() as T)
                                }
                            }
                    }
                    else -> {
                        Observable.just(it.body() as T)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

При дебаге ловлю это:
[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Здравствуйте, в какой строчке кода если поставить дебаг происходит обрыв?

Comment: @TonyLead обрыв происходит не в этих строчках, потому что не получалось отловить 202 код, он приводил к ошибке сразу, но после того как я поменял Response<Any> на Response<ResponseBody> стало работать, только теперь не получается преобразовать json строку к нужному мне типу